# how can I access friends' facebook profile picture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to access friends' profile pictures to display them in my game leaderboard. Most of the links to posts I found here on stackoverflow do not exist anymore. How can I access the profile pictures in a way similar to how I accessed the scores and names in the code below.

```
-(void)getLeaderboardInfo
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/scores?fields=score,user", kuFBAppID] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if (result && !error)
    {

        int index = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [result objectForKey:@"data"])
        {
            NSString *name = [[[[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *strScore = [dict objectForKey:@"score"];

            // how do I get the objectforkey representing the image?

            m_pLeaderboardEntries[index].pFriendName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@", index+1, name];
            m_pLeaderboardEntries[index].pFriendScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %@", strScore];

            // how do I add the image to my leaderboard entries?


            index++;
            if (index>5) {
                break;
            }
            }
        }

     }];
 }
```

The LeaderboardInstance

```
    struct LeaderboardboardInstance
{
    __unsafe_unretained UILabel *pFriendName;
    __unsafe_unretained UILabel *pFriendScore;
    __unsafe_unretained UIImage *profilePicture;
};
```

Also,

```
struct LeaderboardboardInstance m_pLeaderboardEntries[m_kuLeaderboardSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your list of fields

`picture.type(large)`

In the result object you should then have a dictionary called `picture` which contains image info including the `url` of the users image

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please add an example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Facebook user logged in and the friend's Facebook ID, this is the way to go:

```
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", friendID];
```

Then you can download the image using `NSURLConection` or whatever [library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) you want.